# SQL Profiler throws an error : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data, Version = 2.0.0.0?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2008, sql-server-profiler

I installed a third-party SQL Server 2008 R2 toolset a few days ago and then  uninstalled it yesterday. But now when I run SQL Profiler from SSMS, I get an error that says: **Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data, Version = 2.0.0.0**. I re-installed the System.Data for 64-bit and 32-bit versions using gacutil and it did get installed, however, I still see an error when I try to start SQL Profiler from SSMS. Any ideas on how I could fix this other than re-installing SQL Server 2008 R2?

Comment: Can you please specify more exactly - which toolset was that ? Did you try to ask support of the publisher about your problem ?

Comment: I installed trial version of ApexSQL and after I uninstalled it, this problem showed up. Before that I could run SQL Profiler without any problems. I asked the published but they said their software should not do this.

Comment: Ok. That was my first proposal - to ask the publisher of the software. If they say that it was not their uninstaller you could try 2 ways: 1.Put System.Data assembly to folder, where profiler is located, just to make sure that he really needs this assembly. Profiler should start searching in it's current folder first. If it helps - this means that something is with PATHs. 2. As alternative try to run SQL Server install once again and make a "repair". 3.One more option: try to install Apex on another "good" machine, that you could sacrifice and if error repeats you can try again to get support.

Comment: hi - the problem with software vendors is that they will almost never accept that their uninstall process may have caused some issues like BadFormatImage or Could not load file or assembly. But I will try your advice. Appreciate. Thanks. Please write a separate post so I can give you points for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as we have cleared out the best way is to try to localize the problem on another machine and provide Apex with clear instructions how to reproduce it (if bug is caused really by Apex tool). Any good vendor will be thankful for bug, located and reported by user, so they should provide support how to repair your installation.
good luck !